# google places api autocomplete - adding click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm appending a **Search Results** to the google places javascript api autocomplete.

So far I'm doing this:

```
var autocomplete;  
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.738793, -73.991402);
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'));
  }
```

later on I have this:

```
$('.pac-container').append( '<div class="j-search pac-item-refresh">Search Results</div>' );

$(document.body).on('click', '.pac-container .j-search', function(e) {
    console.log('click fired');
});
```

The problem? The click event never fires...

Any idea why? Anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems that the click-event for `.pac-container` is cancelled by the `Autocomplete`-instance. Use `mousedown` instead.

Comment: my gosh! thx a lot! u totally right. - duh! i should have tho about that... thx!

Comment: MOUSEDOWN !! lovely, so long time I haven't used it, I totally forgot about that :p ty

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the this article.
[Implement and Optimize Autocomplete with Google Places API](https://blog.woosmap.com/implement-and-optimize-autocomplete-with-google-places-api)
Specifically Autocompletion using the AutocompleteService:
link: [JS Filddle Of AutocompletionService](https://jsfiddle.net/woosmap/xs8a06nh/)

```js
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  let timeout;
  return function() {
    let context = this,
      args = arguments;
    let later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    let callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
}

function initAutocomplete() {
  let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 48,
      lng: 4
    },
    zoom: 4,
    disableDefaultUI: true
  });

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  let inputContainer = document.querySelector('autocomplete-input-container');
  let autocomplete_results = document.querySelector('.autocomplete-results');
  let service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
  let serviceDetails = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map
  });
  let displaySuggestions = function(predictions, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      alert(status);
      return;
    }
    let results_html = [];
    predictions.forEach(function(prediction) {
      results_html.push(`<li class="autocomplete-item" data-type="place" data-place-id=${prediction.place_id}><span class="autocomplete-icon icon-localities"></span>                   <span class="autocomplete-text">${prediction.description}</span></li>`);
    });
    autocomplete_results.innerHTML = results_html.join("");
    autocomplete_results.style.display = 'block';
    let autocomplete_items = autocomplete_results.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete-item');
    for (let autocomplete_item of autocomplete_items) {
      autocomplete_item.addEventListener('click', function() {
        let prediction = {};
        const selected_text = this.querySelector('.autocomplete-text').textContent;
        const place_id = this.getAttribute('data-place-id');
        let request = {
          placeId: place_id,
          fields: ['name', 'geometry']
        };

        serviceDetails.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            if (!place.geometry) {
              console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
              return;
            }
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
          }
          autocomplete_input.value = selected_text;
          autocomplete_results.style.display = 'none';
        });
      })
    }
  };
  let autocomplete_input = document.getElementById('my-input-autocomplete');
  autocomplete_input.addEventListener('input', debounce(function() {
    let value = this.value;
    value.replace('"', '\\"').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    if (value !== "") {
      service.getPlacePredictions({
        input: value
      }, displaySuggestions);
    } else {
      autocomplete_results.innerHTML = '';
      autocomplete_results.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }, 150));
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  initAutocomplete();
});
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.autocomplete-input-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.autocomplete-input {
  text-align: center;
}

#my-input-autocomplete {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  height: 40px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

#my-input-autocomplete:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.autocomplete-results {
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  width: 320px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  border-top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.autocomplete-item {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 35px;
  height: 26px;
  line-height: 26px;
  border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.autocomplete-icon {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 8px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

.autocomplete-icon.icon-localities {
  background-image: url(https://images.woosmap.com/icons/locality.svg);
}

.autocomplete-item:hover .autocomplete-icon.icon-localities {
  background-image: url(https://images.woosmap.com/icons/locality-selected.svg);
}

.autocomplete-item:hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.autocomplete-results::after {
    content: "";
    padding: 1px 1px 1px 0;
    height: 18px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
    background-image: url(https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/powered-by-google-on-white3_hdpi.png);
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 120px 14px
}
```

```html
<div class="autocomplete-input-container">
  <div class="autocomplete-input">
    <input id="my-input-autocomplete" placeholder="AutocompleteService" autocomplete="off" role="combobox">
  </div>
  <ul class="autocomplete-results">
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback"></script>
```