# Click event on Google Maps API Autocomplete's pac-container divs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to stop propagation of the click event into Google Maps API Autocomplete's dynamically created pac-container divs with no luck.  A similar question has already been asked but the answer doesn't work well for me.
[google places api autocomplete - adding click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250893/google-places-api-autocomplete-adding-click-event)

The solution from that question says that the click event is cancelled by Autocomplete, and to use the mousedown event instead.  That technically worked for me but required me to change the event of document from click to mousedown which is a sacrifice I don't want to make.

I've looked into google maps api events and Autocomplete only emits the 'place_changed' event so no help there.  My code to stop propagation on the pac-container divs below.

```
var pacContainers = document.getElementsByClassName("pac-container");

angular.forEach(pacContainers, function(value, key) {

    // the click event is cancelled by the Autocomplete instance        
    angular.element(value).on('click', function($event) {

        $event.stopPropagation();

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Angular, you can create a directive named pacContainer, and run the code inside your forEach for the element either in the link or controller, and it will bind the click event handler with stopPropagation on any pac-container element as it's created.

Comment: How do I instantiate the pacContainer directive on the google map pac-container divs?  Since they are being added from outside of angular, angular won't know about them in $compile.

Comment: Also, if I were able to instantiate the pacContainer directive, aren't I just trying to manipulate the same click event that google maps autocomplete is already "cancelling"?

Comment: Of course, good point. Same problem there. I'll add another answer with a recommended solution.

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem has been solved before without using intervals or timeouts, and instead using ng-focus to signify the element is ready.

See https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1798#issuecomment-95943955

The pac-container will be ready by the time it receives focus, and that's when you know you can attach the click handler.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  That is a good alternative for using setInterval since I'm using Angular, however,  the question I was asking was with the click event.  I am still left with the same click event issue.

Comment: Hi @DanRichfield Did you find the solution for this problem ? I may need your help to resolve the issue.

Comment: @CrazyGeek I just bit the bullet and used the mousedown event.  everything has been working fine.